# How to test org.hibernate.Session?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, junit4

Hi I have tested this code with junit 4:

```
public class UserDaoTest {
    /**
     * Runs before all test methods
     */
    @BeforeClass
    public static void createDB() {
        sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

        userDao = new UserDaoImpl();
        languageDao = new LanguageDaoImpl();
        requestDao = new RequestDaoImpl();
        feedbackDao = new FeedbackDaoImpl();
        hostelDao = new HostelDaoImpl();
        imageDao = new ImageDaoImpl();
    }

    /**
     * Runs after all test methods
     */
    @AfterClass
    public static void closeSessionFactory() {
        HibernateUtil.shutdown();
    }

    /**
     * Runs before each test method
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Before
    public void beginTransaction() {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    }

    /**
     * Runs after each test method
     */
    @After
    public void rollbackTransaction() {
        if (transaction != null && transaction.isActive()) {    
            System.out.println("Rolling back trasnaction after @Test method");
            // rollback transaction so that tests don't modify database
            transaction.rollback();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSaveUser() { 

        User user1 = new User("Ostap", "Stashyshyn", Gender.MALE);

        // save user. It delegates to `session.save(user1)` method.
        userDao.create(user1);

        Integer userId = user1.getUserId();
        Assert.assertNotNull(userId);

        // causes persistent entities to be saved into persistent context
        session.flush();

        // read languages from db
        List<User> users = userDao.readAll();
        Assert.assertThat(users.size(), CoreMatchers.is(1));

        // next method annotated with @After is running. 
        // It rollbacks transaction causing hibernate not to store data into database. Thus database state is the same as when entering this test method
    }
```

It tests successfully, but when I set breakpoint after `session.flush()` and go to db from command line I see that there is no row for user.

Calling `userDao.readAll();` causes hibernate to issue select statement and return users?

I see insert and select statements on console but nothing in db. But when I call `transaction.commit()` instead of `session.flush()` then appropriate data is in db.

Is above code correct way to test saving user? Or I should call `transaction.commit()` instead of `session.flush()`?

**EDIT**: I shall adhere to this way of testing `org.hibernate.Session`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session used in this test is a different session to the db session you got from command. Until transaction.commit(), you will not see any data changes by your test.

Your test is valid! You should not use transaction.commit() instead of session.flush() as it will persist your test data and make your next run harder.

You only do transaction.commit() instead of session.flush() if you want to debug your test and  verify the test data manually/

Comment: Thanks Bill. I'll use `session.flush()`! I thought that for testing purpose data should be put into db but you say that just synchronizing persistent entities with persistent context is enough. Is this correct?

Comment: the data was in db during the test. however, normally the transaction will be rollback after test finish

Answer (score 1):

`session.flush()` doesn't mean that persistent object will be written to database. `flush` will only responsible for synchronizing the underlying persistent store with persistant state held in memory. in simple word it will update or insert into your tables in the running transaction, but it may not commit those changes all this is depends on `FlushMode` setting.

As the code given by you is not complete so its difficult to tell wther its correct or not. Because what you have written in `userDao.create()` is hiiden? Where you beginning `Transaction` is also not clear.